# System.TriggerOperation enum

Tags: apex, trigger, switch-case

Any examples how to use new System.TriggerOperation enum in a trigger? 
How this code could be replaced:

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (before delete, before insert, before update,   after delete, after insert, after update) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
       if (Trigger.isInsert) { }
    }
```

Comment: Is it [tag:tigger] or [tag:trigger]?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to Summer 18 Apex developer guide, 7 new Enum values are introduced in the `System.TriggerOperation` class.

1. AFTER_DELETE
2. AFTER_INSERT
3. AFTER_UNDELETE
4. AFTER_UPDATE
5. BEFORE_DELETE
6. BEFORE_INSERT
7. BEFORE_UPDATE

Similarly, a new variable is added in Trigger class named as `operationType`, which stores the context enum it is executing in.

Thus your trigger using switch case will be like:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update) {

    switch on Trigger.operationType{
        when AFTER_INSERT{
            //do after insert stuff
        }
        when AFTER_UPDATE{
            //do after update stuff
        } 
    }
}
```

> there is no fall-through. After the code block is executed for a
> particular when block, the switch statement exits

Thus you don't have to add break statement, adding break will cause compilation issues.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_System_TriggerOperation.htm?search_text=TriggerOperation

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html

Comment: Oh, I thought that enum was a joke. That's seriously useful. Time to update all my triggers...

Comment: @sfdcfox even I thought same, Then I saw Daniel Ballinger's idea with delivered tag.

Comment: @sfdcfox Does this mean that using switch with an enum is a less-resource intensive activity than using the if/else/else/else/else, etc pattern that some use?

Comment: Also, I have to wonder if this is a good idea because one would have to store, for example, Trigger.new in the handler class - and if you want to handle every possible enum, you have to store Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, and Trigger.oldMap. Then how do changes to those local variables get populated back to the original passed-in lists and maps?
While switch is nice, I'm unsure that it's going to be a best practice in a trigger handler. Thoughts?

Comment: @DavidSchach You might want to post a question with a full example, but I feel you have a fundamental misunderstanding (or two) about trigger handlers, passing variables by reference, etc.

Comment: That's sweet. A little condescending, though. I probably do have some misunderstandings. Unfortunately, I don't know how to ask the question properly, it seems, which is quite a barrier.  Very open to help, as I'm working on a new template and am unsure if there's one better than Mike Leach's old one, that uses the enum. Simplifying the trigger would be really great, but calling a handler on every action, even to do nothing, seems unnecessary.

Comment: @David can you reach out to me ?(You can find my contact details in my profile) I will try to solve it if not I would post it here on your behalf.

Comment: @sfdcfox Okay, I'm convinced. I wrote a new handler and it's much nicer and uses fewer methods and requires zero changing of the trigger when adding a context action. And I passed everything into one initial method and it all gets handed down without a local or global variable in the handler class.

Comment: @DavidSchach That certainly wasn't my intent, and I apologize that you felt that way. You know that I spend a lot of time and effort trying to help as many people as I can. I'm glad that you were able to work up an example of switch that was able to help you understand better. I've got to re-write all of my triggers, which definitely do have "do-nothing" trigger handler methods right now that can be simplified with switch.